# Anylogic dynamically connections and disconnections

Tags: java, dynamic, anylogic

I'm trying to simulate a model in which I use the `pedestrian library` and `dynamic event`. Especially I use `pedSelectOutput` in order for the passengers to have the opportunity to go to more than one exit.

In the `dynamic event`, in the action part I write:

```
pedSelectOutput.out1.disconnectAndUnmapAll(); 
pedSelectOutput.out1.disconnect(pedGoToExit1.in); 
pedSelectOutput.out1.connect(pedGoToExit2.in);
```

but it seems that it does not work.

Μore specifically, I want to choose the exits dynamically. In addition, I would like to know if I can manage `pedestrians` individually, without creating a new `agent` type. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to explain more for this bit: "I would like to know if I can manage pedestrians individually, without creating a new agent type." If you are using vanilla pedestrians, what "management" would you want to do (since they have no user-defined state or behaviour) given that you use PedSource and PedSink to control the creation/deletion of pedestrians??

Comment: "Manage pedestrians individually". I will try to explain with an example what i mean. My model is a corridor with two exits in which pedestrians go to the exit1 and the exit2. When the dynamic event is created, I want some of the pedestrians that were on the way to the exit1 to change direction and go to the exit2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`portName.connect(...)` and the other functions work only for the establishing of the initial connections. Use `PedExit -> Exit` at `PedSelectOuput` side and `Enter -> PedEnter` at the opposite side. `Exit` and `Enter` blocks belong to the Process Modeling library. They are used for dynamic routing. Call `enterName.take( agent );` in the On Enter action of `Exit` block to forward the agent in the respective `Enter` block.